# optional parameters, or list being mutable or parameter mapping?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and lately the following question puzzled me. The correct output is: [1,2,3]
Could anyone explain to me why? It's so confusing.

```
def f(i, values = []):
    values.append(i)
    return values

f(1)
f(2)
v = f(3)
print(v)
```

Comment: try printing the value of `values` in your function.